# How to run Integration Testing on DB through repositories with LINQ2SQL?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, linq-to-sql, integration-testing

How do you go about integration testing your database through your domain layer/model (repositories) that uses LINQ 2 SQL in the implementation and leave the DB as you found it?  In other words, the ideal world of unit testing the DB, the integration test would leave the DB as it found it.

Are there tools out there that will handle this automagically?  What are the best practices for performing integration tests on a DB through repositories?

Comment: Technically this would be integration testing ;)

Comment: I've been thinking about this recently. I use LINQ2SQL, but I'd like to have a "reference" database in XML. For testing, I'd just switch out the SQL auto-generated stuff with XML auto-generated stuff which is pointing at my file. The tests can easily "roll back" (copy/test/move) the XML file. And I could fine-tune the test data, which would be easy to version control. Unsure how I'd go about getting LINQ to create the a matching XML framework, though. I haven't gotten around to asking about the feasibility or intelligence of this, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Framework [provides support for integration testing when using NUnit](http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.3.0-RC1/reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing).  The NUnit classes are located in the assembly Spring.Testing.NUnit.dll.  In there are some [classes that perform transaction management](http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.3.0-RC1/reference/html/testing.html#testing-tx).  These classes **create and roll back a database transaction for each test**. You simply write code that can assume the existence of a transaction.

Whether or not this will actually work with Linq to SQL is another matter.  Spring says this works with ORMs.  SQL Server 2008 allows you to nest transactions, so in theory you could start a transaction, perform your test through the Linq to SQL classes, and then 
roll your transaction back. But I haven't
 
tried it.

Ryan Garaguay has [an interesting article](http://ryangaraygay.com/blog/post/2008/04/Unit-Testing-Data-Access-with-TransactionScope.aspx) about this which uses [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) and NUnit to roll back the database changes (although he is using SQLCommand and SQLConnection objects in his test code, rather than Linq)